# Could "Search Results" show number of matches?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please Display Match Count after Search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12222/please-display-match-count-after-search)

From the *seems-like-someone-must-have-asked-this-before-but-I-can't-seem-to-find-it* department:

When I do a text search, it would be nice if the screen reported back the number of results. You get the number of results when you do a tag search (i.e. "30 questions tagged `faq`").

It would be nice to quickly see if a regular text search yielded a reasonable number of results or if I was *too general* (i.e. thousands of matches).

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12222/please-display-match-count-after-search.