# Search count missing for search terms that aren't tags

Tags: feature-request, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please Display Match Count after Search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12222/please-display-match-count-after-search)

[Waffles...or something http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/2889/bugreport.jpg](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/2889/bugreport.jpg)

That pretty much sums it up.

EDIT:  I don't really care if the number shows up or not but if we aren't going to get the number now can we at least Capitalize "posts containing" and fix the CSS?  On this page in Firefox 3.5 this causes the gap between the top of first question summary and the bottom of the tab menu line to grow...

Comment: This also occurs for mixed searches (i.e. both tags and non-tags). I wouldn't call it a bug, though, under the assumption that getting tag counts is a lot easier than retrieving the count for a text search

Comment: +1 for the diagram, even though it's a dupe request.