# Should feature proposals which got many upvotes require SO admin feedback?

Tags: discussion, meta, old-questions, feedback

I am a big proponent for this [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12222/please-display-match-count-after-search). (Personally, I think every decent search engine should display a search result count. Google always displays a number at the top and you quickly know if your search terms were too broad)

Anyways, I am interested to know what's the plan for this request? It was upvoted many times. No one is objecting. It's a year old. So what happened? Did it fall through the cracks? How do we know such proposals are still being considered and not forgotten? Do old proposals need to be revived in some fashion? Do the SO folks think it's a stupid idea?

These proposals need a follow up so we don't have these questions.

Comment: Answer here: [Admin Feedback](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56010/does-the-team-actually-pay-special-attention-to-featured-questions-on-meta)

Comment: I don't see a good answer. Jeff says he looks at the proposals. Then what? I am requesting a feedback on upvoted proposals. If it's hard to do, then say it's hard to do and we won't think about it again.

Answer (score 8):

It was upvoted 14 times, to be precise.

There are [a few things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=requests) in front of it.

Comment: All the ones in req I checked came after the above proposal. Not sure what kind of priority type you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Proposals are often tagged as `[status-planned]`, `[status-deferred]` or `[status-declined]` before they are ultimately `[status-completed]`. However, as you point out, there are lots that are in limbo.

I don't think you can "require" that the owners of the site post some kind of administrative response to a request. It would be nice if they did - but you can't force them.

Answer (score 0):

The administrators have a finite amount of time to work with.

#### Time Served

If Jeff were to spend all of his time *responding* to Meta requests, then he would have no time for *implementing* meta requests. Also no time for [Rock Hard Awesome](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/spawned-a-new-process.html). So he responds to as many as he can, and adds relevant tags to others.

#### Responding When You Have A *Response*

This is not a one man show. While Jeff is certainly the top of the pyramid, there are lots of internal team discussions. This means that certain requests are put on the shelf until they are important enough to be discussed by the *team*. Until that time, there *is no response*. Or rather no response **is** the response.

#### Status Deferred On Everything

If you are going to *require* a response, you'll either get *rushed* responses, or *bad* responses. Either that or Mr. Atwood will just tag *everything* with [status-deferred] until they get around to discussing it. But currently, [status-deferred] essentially means that they have considered it and will reconsider it later.

So, ultimately, we need to let them work their way through the issues at their own pace. Of *course* it will be frustrating to those of us with pet feature-requests that we care about more than all others. But the team is working as fast as they can.